# Warnings when compiling a Linked List code in java

Tags: java, list, compiler-construction, linked-list, warnings

I am trying to write a simple code to implement Linked List in Java using java.util.LinkedList library. I have tried my best to keep it error-free.

It does compile (and execute) using -Xlint:unchecked. But it generates a LOT of warnings of the type - LL.java:25: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type LinkedList

Can someone help me
 1. Comprehend why is it happening?
 2. Remove the warnings!

Any help will be appreciated...

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

class LL{
public static void main(String[] args){

    //creating a new linked list object
    LinkedList LLobj = new LinkedList();

    //adding data to linked list
    LLobj.add("T");
    LLobj.add("H");
    LLobj.add("I");
    LLobj.add("S");
    LLobj.add(" ");
    LLobj.add("I");
    LLobj.add("S");
    LLobj.add(" ");
    LLobj.add("A");
    LLobj.add(" ");
    LLobj.add("L");
    LLobj.add("I");
    LLobj.add("N");
    LLobj.add("K");
    LLobj.add("E");
    LLobj.add("D");
    LLobj.add("-");
    LLobj.add("L");
    LLobj.add("I");
    LLobj.add("S");
    LLobj.add("T");

    //printing the linked list
    System.out.println(LLobj);

    //Implementing more functions to add data
    LLobj.addFirst("#");
    LLobj.addLast("#");
    LLobj.add(5,"$");

    //printing the linked list
    System.out.println(LLobj);

    //removing data
    LLobj.remove("$");
    LLobj.remove("#");
    LLobj.remove("#");

    //printing the linked list
    System.out.println(LLobj);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the warning you are getting? I think you need to use Generic type, maybe that's the warning.

Comment: You need to learn about generics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you're using a generic type ([`LinkedList<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)) but you're using it as the *raw* type, as if you didn't know about generics. You want something like this:

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

list.add("T");
list.add("H");
```

That way you're *safe* in terms of the types involved, and you know that everything in the list is a string.

In Java 7 you can use ["diamond syntax"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html) to infer the type on the right hand side from the left:

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
```

For *much* more about generics (including raw types), see the [Java generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html). Also note how in my example I renamed your `LLobj` variable name (which doesn't follow Java naming conventions) to just `list`. It's a good idea to follow the naming conventions at all times, especially when sharing code with others.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to specify the type of the linked list, as follows:

```
LinkedList<String> LLobj = new LinkedList<>();
```

This will tell the compiler that only `String`s will be used and therefore the safety of the `.add()` methods, as they will accept only `String` inputs (as `String` is a `final` class and cannot be `extend`ed).

Comment: Assuming he's using Java 7.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
LinkedList LLobj = new LinkedList();
```

to

```
LinkedList<String> LLobj = new LinkedList<String>();
```

This will resolve all those type safety warning, since now the compiler will know that you are intending to keep `String`s in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Give it a type

example:

```
LinkedList<String> LLobj = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Answer (score 1):

The code : `LinkedList LLobj = new LinkedList();` must be replaced with `LinkedList<String> LLobj = new LinkedList<String>();`

Compiler will warn you because you are not using generics in your code i.e. type of objects you need to hold in your list. By not using generics in your code, you can enter any type of object in the list  like : `LLobj.add(new Integer(10)); LLobj.add("ABC");`

**This will result in ClassCastException** as you dont know which type of object will be coming from the list It can be a String or a Integer. Hence it gives warning messages.
By using specific types like `LinkedList<String> LLobj = new LinkedList<String>();` you can only add String to your list and hence **no ClassCastException** will occur at any place.